Sub division rings of dimension 2 of division rings
Suppose $A$ is a division ring and $B$ is a sub division ring  such that $A$, as a left vector space over $B$, has dimension $2$.
Is it true that $B$ must be commutative ?

No. The first example that occured to me is to choose the division algebra $I$ of Icosians for the role of $A$, and the division algebra of rational Hamiltonian quaternions $H$ for $B$.
We have
$$H=\{a+bi+cj+dk\mid a,b,c,d\in\Bbb{Q}\}\subset\Bbb{H}$$
and we get the icosians by extending the center of $H$ from $\Bbb{Q}$ to $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt5)$:
$$I=\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt5)\otimes_{\Bbb{Q}}H.$$
$I$ is still a subset of the division algebra $\Bbb{H}$ (with real $a,b,c,d$), and $\dim_HI=[\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt5):\Bbb{Q}]=2$.
